# Converting 24 bit USB audio stream into 32 bit stream

Tags: audio, usb, signal-processing

I'm trying to convert a 24 bit usb audio stream into a 32 bit stream so my microcontroller's peripherals can play happily with the stream (it can only handle 16 or 32 bit data like most mcus...).

The following code is what I got from the mcu's company... didn't work as expected and I ended up getting really distorted audio.

```
// Function takes usb stream and processes the data for our peripherals
// @data         - usb stream data
// @byte_count   - size of stream 
void process_usb_stream(uint8_t *data, uint16_t byte_count) {
     // Etc code that gets buffers ready to read the stream...
     // Conversion here!
     int32_t *buffer;
     int sample_count = 0;
     for (int i = 0; i < byte_count; i += 3) {
         buffer[sample_count++] = data[i] | data[i+1] << 8 | data[i+2] << 16;
     }
     // Send buffer to peripherals for them to use...
}
```

Any help with converting the data from a 24 bit stream to 32 bit stream would be super awesome! This area of work is very hard for me :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`data[...]` is a uint8_t.  You need to cast that before shifting, because `data[...]<<8` and `data[...]<<16` are undefined.  They'll either be 0 or unchanged, neither of which is what you want.

Also, you need to shift by another 8 bits to get the full range and put the sign bit in the right place.

Also, you're treating the data as if it were in little-endian format.  Make sure it is.  I'll assume that's correct, so something like this works:

```
 int32_t *buffer;
 int sample_count = 0;
 for (int i = 0; i+3 <= byte_count; ) {
     int32_t v = ((int32_t)data[i++])<<8;
     v |= ((int32_t)data[i++])<<16;
     v |= ((int32_t)data[i++])<<24;
     buffer[sample_count++] = v;
 }
```

Finally, note that this assumes that byte_count is divisible by 3 -- make sure that's true!

Comment: Hi Matt, when you put `int32_t`, you're saying it should be signed data? Shoudn't I be putting it in a `uint32_t` type?

Comment: Both signed and unsigned 24-bit and 32-bit formats are used, but I think the signed formats are more common.  I assumed they were both signed, because you specified `int32_t *buffer` and were stuffing bytes into it without doing any sign conversion.

Comment: Ah makes sense. And yea I was looking at the example code again to make sure that's what they put and yes they did put a signed 32-bit integer. I'll try out your algorithm!

Answer (score 1):

this is DSP stuff if, also post this question on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

In DSP the process of changing the bit depth is called *scaling*

- 16 bit resolution has 65536 values
- 24 bit resolution has 16777216
  possible values
- 32 bit has 4294967296 values so the factor is 256

According to https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/229268/what-is-name-of-process-used-to-change-sample-bit-depth/229271
reduction from 24 bit to 16 bit is called *scaling down* and is done by dividing each value by 256.

This can be done by bitwise shifting every bit by 8
`y = x >> 8`. When scaling down this way the LSB is lost

*Scaling up* to 32 bit is more complicated and there are several approaches how to do this. It may work by multiplying each bit of the value with a value between 2⁰ and 2⁸.

Push the 24 bit value in a 32 bit register and then left-shifting each bit by a value between 2⁰ and 2⁸:

```
data32[31] = data32[23] << 8;
data32[22] = data32[14] << 8;
...
data32[0] = data32[0];
```

and interpolate the bits you do not get with this (linear interpolation)

Maybe there are much better scaling up algortihms ask on http://dsp.stackexchange.com

See also http://blog.bjornroche.com/2013/05/the-abcs-of-pcm-uncompressed-digital.html for the scaling up problem...

Comment: Thanks! In hindsight I should've posted in the DSP section as well haha. I'll look into these links and let you know what I get! But this is definitely what I was looking for, thanks!